# Need Explanation For Multiple Arguments And Input Redirection With Cat

Tags: io-redirection, cat, file-descriptors

Files along with their contents:-

```
~$cat a
aaa
aaa
aaa
~$cat b
bbb
bbb
bbb
~$cat c
ccc
ccc
ccc
```

Commands that I need explanation:-

```
~$cat 0< a
aaa
aaa
aaa
~$cat 0< a b
bbb
bbb
bbb
~$cat 0< a b c
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
ccc
```

I need an explanation as to why contents of file 'a' were printed when I executed `~$cat 0< a` and why the contents of file 'a' were not printed when I executed `~$cat 0< a b` or `~$cat 0< a b c`.

Comment: (1) I presume that you realize that `0<` is equivalent to just plain `<`, and so nobody ever says `0<`.  (2) Nobody else seems to have explained the real answer to your question (or, at least, the entire answer), namely, your commands are equivalent to `cat < a`, `cat b  < a`, and `cat b c  < a`, because I/O redirection is not an argument, and is not visible directly to the command, and can be placed anywhere in the command line.  So, in the first case, `cat` is being run with no arguments, while in the other cases it is being run with filename argument(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat` reads `stdin` if run without arguments. If you give it arguments, it will read the arguments and not `stdin`.
If you want it to read both its argument files and `stdin`, make `/dev/stdin` one of the arguments (according to where you want it to go in the concatenation):

```
cat 0<a /dev/stdin b c
```

**Notes:**

- `-` or `/dev/fd/0` also works
- `0<` can simply be `<`

Comment: `-` is better since it doesn't rely on the explicit existence of those special device files. (Usually those are there, but during system startup or installation, or if `/proc` isn't mounted, they might not be.) So, to the OP: `cat - b c <a` will print out file `a` then `b` then `c`. You could mix it up: `cat a - c < b` which will print out the files in the same order as before.

Comment: @Otheus I prefer the `/dev` devices. It's cleaner. No special treatment for a magic argument of `-` dependent on each individual application. Getting rid of the `-` = `stdin`  convention is one of the reasons why those dev devices were created.

Comment: `cat -`, however, is defined by the POSIX standard. Neither `/dev/stdin` nor `/dev/fd/0` is.